# Upper Hemicontinuous Correspondence has Nonempty Values?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Here is Theorem 17.16 from From Aliprantis and Border:

> For a correspondence $\varphi: X \twoheadrightarrow Y$ between
> topological spaces and a point $x \in X$, the following are
> equivalent: \
>
> 1. $\varphi$ is upper hemicontinuous at $x$ and $\varphi(x)$ is compact.
> 2. For every net $\{(x_\alpha, y_\alpha)\}$ in the graph of $\varphi$, that is, with $y_\alpha \in \varphi(x_\alpha)$ for each
>    $\alpha$, if $x_\alpha \to x$, then the net $\{y_\alpha\}$ has a limit
>    point in $\varphi(x)$.

Now, here is how the proof begins:

> *Proof:* [(1) implies (2)] Assume that $\varphi$ is upper hemicontinuous at $x \in X$, with $\varphi(x)$ compact. Let $x_\alpha \to x$, and let $y_\alpha \in \varphi(x_\alpha)$ for each $\alpha$.
> **Notice that the upper hemicontinuity of $\varphi$ at $x$ guarantees that $\varphi(x) \ne \emptyset$.**

For the life of me, I cannot see why $\varphi(x) \ne \emptyset$. I assume that this is supposed to follow directly from the definition of upper hemicontinuity; that is,

> $\varphi$ is **upper hemicontinuous** at $x$ if for every neighborhood
> $U$ of $\varphi(x)$, there is a neighbhorhood $V$ of $x$ such that $z \in V$ implies $\varphi(z) \subset U$.

Ok. Well, in pursuit of a contradiction, let's suppose that $\varphi(x) = \emptyset$. Now, let $U$ be a neighborhood of $\varphi(x) = \emptyset$ (so, the extreme case would be $U = \emptyset$). Then, since $\varphi$ is upperhemicontinuous, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $z \in V$ implies $\varphi(z)$. So choose such a neighborhood $V$ (which we will assume is open). Then, since $x_\alpha \to x$, there is some $\lambda$ such that $x_{\alpha} \in V$ whenever $\alpha \ge \lambda$. This means that $\varphi(x_{\alpha}) \subset U$ whenever $\alpha \ge \lambda$. If $U = \emptyset$, this means $\varphi(x_\alpha) = \emptyset$ whenever $\alpha \ge \lambda$. I still am not seeing a problem here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\varphi(x)=\emptyset$ then $\emptyset$ is a neighborhood of $\varphi(x)$. If you take a neighborhood $V$ of $x$, then you have some $x_\alpha$ in $V$. But then this means $\varphi(x_\alpha)\subset \emptyset$ by upper hemicontinuity, which can’t be.

Comment: I still do not see a contradiction. For example: Suppose $\varphi(x) = \emptyset$ for every $x \in X$. Let $V$ be an open subset of $Y$. Then $\varphi^{\text{u}}(V) = \{x \in X : \varphi(x) \subset V\} = X$. Since $X$ is an open subset of $X$, $\varphi$ is upper hemicontinuous.

Comment: Because $x_\alpha\to x$, for any neighborhood $V$ of $x$, there will be a $x_\alpha\in V$. But $\varphi(x_\alpha)\not=\emptyset$. The contradiction then is that $\varphi$ is not upper hemicontinuous if $\varphi(x)=\emptyset$ because $\varphi(V)\not\subset \varphi(x)=\emptyset$.

Comment: Ah. Yes, I somehow forgot about the assumption that $y_\alpha \in \varphi(x_\alpha)$ for each $\alpha$.